# Send a message to webhook with data from char variables using libcurl in C

Tags: c

I wrote this C code and I don't know how to put variables my_username, my_description and my_title in message variable instead of USER, DESCRIPTION and TITLE. Is there anyone here who can help me? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define nullptr ((void*)0)    

int main() {

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

char my_username[] = "My User";
int my_description = 10;
char my_title[] = "My Title";

char webhook[] = "DISCORD_WEBHOOK";
char message[] = "{\"username\": \"USER\",\"embeds\":[{\"description\": \"DESCRIPTION\", \"title\": \"TITLE\", \"color\":1018364}]}";

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    struct curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, webhook);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, message);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the function `sprintf`

Comment: I recommend you don't write this type of software in C if you don't have the required experience. You should not really use `snprintf` for JSON, but you could use it here. It's better to use a JSON library, which you will already need to write this type of application.

Comment: It works with snprintf, thanks!